# How to map scalar twig filter to array

Tags: twig, higher-order-functions, twig-filter

I have a simple array of floats. And I need to show it as comma separated string.

```
{{ arr|join(', ') }}
```

is bad solution because of excessive insignificant accuracy.

```
{% for val in arr %}
    {{val|number_format(2)}},
{% endfor %}
```

is bad because of extra comma at the end.

I would like to do something like this:

```
{{ arr|map(number_format(3))|join(', ') }}
```

but I have not found filter `map` or similar filter it Twig. 
Аnd I don't know how to implement such filter.

Comment: You can add existing functions to [twig](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twig/4923/extending-twig/17380/adding-custom-filters-functions#t=201610242001086557364)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- This question relates to higher-order functions

  - Map is a higher-order function
  - (see eg) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)
  - (see eg) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- Twig 2.x (latest version as of Wed 2017-02-08)

#### Problem

- **Scenario:** DeveloperGarricSugas wishes to apply higher-order function(s) to a Twig variable

  - Higher order functions allow any of various transformations on any Twig variable
- Twig support for higher-order functions is limited
- Nevertheless, there exist addon libraries for this

  - (see eg) https://github.com/dpolac/twig-lambda
- Custom filters or functions can also be used to simulate this

#### Example

- DeveloperGarricSugas starts with a sequentially-indexed array
- transform from `BEFORE` into `AFTER` (uppercase first letter)

```
{%- set mylist = ['alpha','bravo','charlie','delta','echo']  -%}

BEFORE: 
['alpha','bravo','charlie','delta','echo']

AFTER: 
['Alpha','Bravo','Charlie','Delta','Echo']
```

#### Solution

```
{%- set mylist = mylist|map(=> _|capitalize)  -%}
```

#### Pitfalls

- Twig higher-order functions limited support comes from addon-libraries
- The above solution does not work with native Twig

#### See also

- https://twigfiddle.com/rsl89m
- https://github.com/dpolac/twig-lambda

Comment: Please correct syntax: `mylist|map(=> _|capitalize)`

Comment: It looks as though there is now a version of `map`, with slightly different syntax, in Twig core. https://symfony.com/blog/twig-adds-filter-map-and-reduce-features

Answer (score 8):

Why not use the `loop` variable?

```
{% for val in arr %}
    {{val|number_format(2)}}
    {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: OK, this is the solution for my example. But this is not a solution for the subject topic. You prefer to write a new analogue of an existing filter `join`... But can't we use the standard `join` filter for this?

Comment: You can write a new filter to use array_map under the hood, but join has no such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- alternate approach is to use Twig loops (workaround)

### Workaround

```
{%- set aaold = [1.234,234.56,11.222,22.333]  -%}
{%- set aanew = []  -%}
{% for item in aaold -%}
  {{ aanew|merge(item|number_format(3)) }}
{% endfor %}
{{ aanew | join(', ') }}
```

### Pitfalls

- requires use of `array|merge`

  - alternative to `array|merge` ... `loop.first` or `loop.last` as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40224624/42223)
- requires addition of loop control structure that means extra code bloat