# Apply filter to each item in array and then JSON encode it using Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have an array of phone numbers

```
[ '1234567', '98765423' ... ]
```

and I want to first apply my custom filter `phone` to it, then render the result in `JSON` format.

I tried

```
{{ numbersArray | phone | json_encode }}
```

but it gives me an error because it is expecting a string and not an array.

Is there a way to make Twig apply the `phone` filter to each individual array item, and then apply `json_encode` to the filtered array?

Comment: Use loop `foreach` to apply filter to each element of array

Comment: @J.Litvak Thanks for the suggestion, but as I'm passing the result as JSON I'd like to avoid using logic like that in the template. Then I might as well just do it in the controller instead.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42122691/9135269) that discusses about the possibility of using higher-order functions like [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) in twig.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I had to modify my `phone` filter to accept both `string` and `array`:

```
$twig->getEnvironment()->addFilter(new \Twig_SimpleFilter('phone', function ($input) {
    if( is_array($input) ){
        $result = [];
        foreach( $input as $number ) {
            $result[] = formatNumber($number);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    return formatNumber($input); 
}));
```

Comment: Just a shorter [variant](https://pastebin.com/3408eMbp) on how I handle possible string/array parameters in `twig`

Comment: @DarkBee Nice, but the result will be an array even when the input is a string. Can see how that could cause confusion and head scratching later on...

Comment: `array_map` would be nice here: `return is_array($input) ? array_map('formatNumber', $input) : formatNumber($input);`